# Any way to speed up / optimize facebook multi query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm running a series of queries to find recent location posts of friends, get the users profile data and place info. The only way i've been able to do this is with 4 queries which seems to benchmark around the 800ms range, not very fast. Query looks like this

```
 {
  "posts": "select id,app_id,author_uid,post_id,message,post_id,tagged_uids,page_id,timestamp from location_post where author_uid in (select uid2 from #friends) and timestamp < 1393537146 order by timestamp desc limit 3",
  "placenames": "select name from page where page_id in (select page_id from #posts)",
  "friends": "select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()",
  "usernames": "select name,uid,pic from user where uid in (select author_uid from #posts)"
}
```

I think where it really hangs up is the first query is the "friends one" so it queries all the friends and then uses this to look for recent posts.

Any optimization advice or other strategies would be appreciated.

Comment: "I think where it really hangs up is the first query" --- have you tried to remove that query to confirm your guess?

Comment: I can't remove it, the others will fail. They are not independent of each other.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried to run only the first one? Then the second one, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could at least wrap the friends query inside the posts query, because it's only referenced there, like this:

```
{
  "posts": "select id,app_id,author_uid,post_id,message,post_id,tagged_uids,page_id,timestamp from location_post where author_uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) and timestamp < 1393537146 order by timestamp desc limit 3",
  "placenames": "select name from page where page_id in (select page_id from #posts)",
  "usernames": "select name,uid,pic from user where uid in (select author_uid from #posts)"
}
```